# Exclamatives or Free relatives

Tags: free-relative-clauses, exclamatives

> "Tell us," said Mahony pertly to the man, "how many have
>   you yourself?"
>    The man smiled as before and said that
>   when he was our age he had lots of sweethearts.
>     "Every boy," he said, "has a little sweetheart."
>     His attitude on this point struck me as strangely liberal
>   in a man of his age. In my heart I thought that what he said about
>   boys and sweethearts was reasonable. But I disliked the words in his
>   mouth and I wondered why he shivered once or twice as if he feared
>   something or felt a sudden chill. As he proceeded I noticed that his
>   accent was good. He began to speak to us about girls, saying
>   ***what*** (1) nice soft hair they had and ***how*** (2) soft their hands were and ***how*** (3) all girls were not so good as they seemed
>   to be if one only knew. There was nothing he liked, he said, so much
>   as looking at a nice young girl, at her nice white hands and her
>   beautiful soft hair. He gave me the impression that he was repeating
>   something which he had learned by heart or that, magnetised by some
>   words of his own speech, his mind was slowly circling round and round
>   in the same orbit. (James Joyce, Dubliners)

*What* (1), *how* (2), and *how* (3), all, I suspect, exclamatives, at least they are acting as intensifiers. But I don’t find any grounds for it. Are they just free relatives or something intensifying? Or do the free relatives themselves have the intensifying meaning themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very interesting use, on the borderline between ordinary free relative and exclamative.

That is, it is ambiguous whether the man actually said something like "What nice soft hair they have!" "How soft their hands are!" or whether he spoke less vivaciously **about** what nice soft hair they have and **about** how soft their hands are.

But the ambiguity is resolved with the final piece: there is no way that *how all girls were not so good as they seemed to be* can be understood as an exclamative.

- In the first place, these exclamative uses assert that their complements exhibit some quality in an unusual degree, so they require terms which can sustain a comparison:

  > How soft her hair is! ... *Her hair is softer than other girls'.*
  >   What a man he is! ... *He exhibits more manliness than other men.*
- In the second place, there must be 'agreement' between the head and the complement. *What* takes a nominal complement, and *how* takes an adjective, adverb or verb:

  > How soft her hair is!
  >   How well he speaks!
  >   How she struts!

I don't think *How they are not so good as they seem to be* qualifies under either requirement. An exclamatory would have to be something more like:

> How much worse they are than they seem!
>   How wickedly they conceal their true depravity!

Consequently, I read these as ordinary free relatives naming the tenor of the man's discourse.