# confusing hows: (i) used to express surprise, pleasure, etc. (ii) the fact that, the way that

Tags: conjunctions

I’m embarrassing whenever I come across how clauses. The two meanings –– (i) [used to express surprise, pleasure, etc](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/how).  (ii) [that, the fact that, the way that](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/how) –– are especially confusing. Would you check which of the two do I have to pick up in next examples? Are there any patterns that I attend to?

- It seems like *the way* in 5 can be replaced by *how* without semantic change.

> 1
>   The Potters knew very well what he and Petunia thought aboutthem and their kind.... He couldn't see **how** he and Petunia could get mixed up in anything that might be going on –– he yawned and turned over –– it couldn't affect them....

–– Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, p.8

> 2
>   There was a horrible smell in the kitchen the next morning when Harry went in for breakfast. It seemed to be coming from a large metal tub in the sink. He went to have a look. The tub was full of what looked like dirty rags swimming in gray water.
>
> "What's this?" he asked Aunt Petunia. Her lips tightened as they always did if he dared to ask a question.
>
> "Your new school uniform," she said.
>
> Harry looked in the bowl again.
>
> "Oh," he said, "I didn't realize it had to be so wet."
>
> "Don’t be stupid," snapped Aunt Petunia. "I'm dyeing some of Dudley's old things gray for you. It'll look just like everyone else's when I've finished."
>
> Harry seriously doubted this, but thought it best not to argue. He sat down at the table and tried not to think about **how** he was going to look on his first day at Stonewall High -- like he was wearing bits of old elephant skin, probably.

–– Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, p.33

> 3
>   Griphook unlocked the door. A lot of green smoke came billowing out, and as it cleared, Harry gasped. Inside were mounds of gold coins. Columns of silver. Heaps of little bronze Knuts.
>
> "All yours," smiled Hagrid.
>
> All Harry's –– it was incredible.The Dursleys couldn't have known about this or they'd have had it from him faster than blinking. How often had they complained **how** much Harry cost them to keep?

–– Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, p.75

> 4
>   Then she changed her desk into a pig and back again. They were all very impressed and couldn't wait to get started, but soon realized they weren't going to be changing the furniture into animals for a long time. After taking a lot of complicated notes, they were each given a match and started trying to turn it into a needle. By the end of the lesson, only Hermione Granger had made any difference to her match; Professor McGonagall showed the class **how** it had gone all silver and pointy and gave Hermione a rare smile.

–– Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, p.134

> 5
>   Malfoy had been even more unpleasant than usual since the Quidditch match. Disgusted that the Slytherins had lost, he had tried to get everyone laughing at **how** a wide-mouthed tree frog would be replacing Harry as Seeker next. Then he'd realized that nobody found this funny, because they were all so impressed at **the way** Harry had managed to stay on his bucking broomstick. So Malfoy, jealous and angry, had gone back to taunting Harry about having no proper family.

–– Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, p.195

> 6
>   “There’s this real Al Capone fear that they’re going to get our guys, not on marijuana, but on something else,” Mr. Edson said, referring to **how** Capone was eventually charged with tax evasion rather than criminal activity. - [witioanry.org](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/04/24/us/24pot.html)
>
> 7
>   Ron was fascinated by the fifty pence.
>
> "Weird!" he said, 'What a shape! This is money?"
>
> "You can keep it," said Harry, laughing at **how** pleased Ron was.

–– Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, p.200

> 8
>   "So the Stone's gone?" said Ron finally. "Flamel's just going to die?"
>
> "That's what I said, but Dumbledore thinks that –– what was it? –– 'to
>   the well-organized mind, death is but the next great adventure.’”
>
> "I always said he was off his rocker," said Ron, looking quite
>   impressed at **how** crazy his hero was.

–– Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, p.302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUPPLEMENTAL to Damkerng T.'s answer:

The two “definitions” you offer exhibit a difference not of meaning but of use.

*How* indeed has two slightly different senses, which Damkerng T. discriminates nicely:

- ***in what way*** ... or *manner* or *by what means* or *method*. In this sense *how* modifies a verb or clause.
- ***to what extent*** ... or *degree* or *level*. In this sense *how* modifies an adjective or adverb.

There is some overlap, however. Consider this sentence:

> I can't stand how he’s always bragging about his grades.

Here the *how* implies distaste for the extent of his bragging as well as its manner—*how much* or *how often* he brags as well as his self-satisfaction.

Consequently, in the present context it may be more useful to regard ***in what way*** as the primary sense, with a number of secondary senses (there are more, but these are the ones reflected in your examples):

1. ***in what manner***
2. ***by what means*** or ***method***
3. ***by what events***
4. ***in what state*** or ***condition*** (with verbs of appearance)
5. ***to what degree*** ... This ordinarily ‘modifies’ an adjective or adverb, but the sense is also apparent when it modifies a verb or clause, as in my ‘bragging’ example:

   > I can't stand how<sup>5</sup> he’s always bragging about his grades.

In any of these senses *how* may be deployed in two ways:

- as an **interrogative**
  *How<sup>1</sup> did the kids behave today?*
  *How<sup>2</sup> did you do that?* 
  *How<sup>3</sup> did the fire start?*
  *How<sup>4</sup> does Ryan look today?*
  *How<sup>5</sup> old are you?*
- as the head of a **free relative clause**
  *I was appalled at how<sup>1</sup> the kids behaved today.*
  *Show me how<sup>2</sup> you did that.*
  *The report explains how<sup>3</sup> the fire started.*
  *Pretty beat up was how<sup>4</sup> he looked to me.*
  *How<sup>5</sup> old you are determines which class you compete in.*

All of your examples are free relatives, and most reflect one of those uses:

> 1 ... how<sup>3</sup> he and Petunia could get mixed up ...
>      2 ... how<sup>4</sup> he was going to look ...
>      3 ... how<sup>5</sup> much Harry cost them ...
>      7 ... how<sup>5</sup> pleased Ron was ...
>      8 ... how<sup>5</sup> crazy his hero was

In free relative clauses, two of the secondary senses have evolved secondary uses.

- *How<sup>3</sup>* has taken on what [***OED 1***](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdicpt105murruoft#page/428/mode/2up), **How, 10.**, calls a ‘weakened meaning’ (I would call it a ‘generalized’ meaning) equivalent to the complementizer *that*. Three of your examples reflect this use:

  > 4 ... how it had gone all silver and pointy
  >      5 ... how a wide-mouthed tree frog would be replacing Harry
  >      6 ... how Capone was eventually charged with tax evasion
- *How<sup>5</sup>* may be employed as an exclamation to call attention to the exciting or pleasing or dismaying degree of whatever-it-is is exhibited. This use may be identified by its syntactic role: it stands alone, not embedded as a constituent within a sentence<sup>†</sup>, and it is usually written with an exclamation mark. **This exclamative use is not represented in your examples**, but any of the *how<sup>5</sup>s* could be recast as such an exclamation:

  > How much Harry costs us!
  >   How pleased Ron is!
  >   How crazy Dumbledore is!

  It should perhaps be remarked that this use has been infrequent in US speech as far back as I can remember, and I suspect it had become a largely literary use long before that. American speakers are much more likely to embed such a free relative:

  > I can’t believe how much Harry costs us!
  >   Just look at how pleased Ron is!
  >   I’m blown away by how crazy Dumbledore is!

---

<sup>†</sup> except of course as a quotation standing as the object of *he said* or something of that sort. You may recall the ambiguity which arises when such a quotation is embedded, or apprarently embedded, in indirect discourse; we discussed that [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9484/).

Comment: I'm very much obliged to this long heartfelt article. This very question on about these very examples were about over a year long, and finally I got a light.

Answer (score 3):

Except for common phrases such as *"How are you?"* or *"How was it?"*, which I believe most of the learners know the translations in their first language well, I use this trick to tell which sense I should use.

It is to choose between **in what way** and **to what extent**.

In my first language (Thai), we have different words for these two senses. (And, I suspect that you might have different words for these senses in Korean too.) This is perfectly helpful.

The fine contrast between the two senses can be found in the *Usage notes* of the [Wiktionary link](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/how),

> *How good is it?* means "To what extent is it good?", whereas *How is it good?* means "In what manner is it good?". Likewise, *I know how good it is* means "I know the extent to which it is good", whereas *I know how it is good* means "I know the manner in which it is good".

This explains why we interpret **how [adj.]** in the sense of **to what extent**, e.g., *How kind of you to help!* and most of **how [clause]** in the sense of **in what way**, e.g. *He couldn't see how he and Petunia could get mixed up*.

In your passages, the marked *how*'s, except for *how much* (3), *how pleased* (7), and *how crazy* (8), should all be interpreted as **in what way**.

And yes, I agree that you can use *how* in the place of *the way* in *"... they were all so impressed at **the way** Harry had managed to ..."* (I believe that you can even drop that *at* too, i.e. *"... they were all so impressed **how** Harry had managed to ..."*.)

Comment: You see (1),(2);(4),(5),(6) all are to be interpreted as ‘in what way’. But there seems some difference between the first two and the latter three. I don’t see any semantic blank in the latter how-clauses; I guess the first two can take adjunct or complement.I guess that’s the dividing criteria of adverb (in what manner) and conjunction (that, the fact/way that) in [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/how), but I don’t find any grounds. You see [snailboat](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14086/what-does-this-how-mean/14087#14087) see the how of 4 as a complementizer not an adverb.

Comment: I agree with snailboat, especially that you can  replace that *how* with *that*. In fact, I think (1),(2),(4),(5),(6) are all subordinate clauses, with *how* as the conjunction. You can replace these *how*'s with either *that* or *the way that*. (In my first language, *that* and *the way that* in these cases mean the same thing, and I think you will have a mixed sense in your examples too.)

Answer (score 2):

"How" can be changed to "the way" in all examples you mentioned, except for:

On page 75, "how much" is a two word phrase, refering to amounts.

> they complained **how much** Harry cost
>
> they complained **about the amount of money that** Harry cost

In the first example on page 109, "how" can be replaced by "the fact that".

> laughing at **how** a wide-mouthed tree frog would
>
> laughing at **the fact that** a wide-mouthed tree frog would

Again in the Capone example:

> referring to **how** Capone was eventually
>
> referring to **the fact that** Capone was eventually

These are a bit weirder:

> laughing at **how pleased** Ron was.
>
> impressed at **how crazy** his hero was.

These basically also mean "the amount of". There's no good replacement for these though.

I would rephrase it from

> I'm delighted at **how clean** the floor is.

to something sort of like

> The floor is **so clean that** I feel delighted about it.

to understand it better.

Unfortunately, "how" is one of those words that changes a lot depending on context. It takes a bit of memorization, I think. You'll get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

All of the examples except 3 use how meaning "the way that" definition.

1. Uncle Vernon doesn't see any **way that** his in-laws being wizards would affect the Dursleys.
2. Harry is imagining **the way that** his uniform will look on him-- "like he was wearing bits of old elephant skin."

On 3, I think the confusion comes from the fact that "how" is being used as part of the phrase "how much." This is used to refer to an amount of money. In the example, Harry's relatives are always complaining about the amount of money they have to spend on Harry.